# How to select words after /slash from a json file in a powershell script

Tags: json, parsing, text-parsing

I've a json file from a az cli command, I want to deploy with a powershell script from a tool like jenkins or rundeck, I need to take the field "name" from json but not entirely  only the word after forward slash

```
    [
  {
    "Group": "KC-EMEA-RSGP-BPTRAINING-01",
    "id": "/subscriptions/KC-EMEA-RSGP-BPTRAINING-01/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/",
    "name": "kc-emea-sqsrv-bptraining-dev-01/master"
  },
  {
    "Group": "KC-EMEA-RSGP-NAVISIONKM-DEV-01",
    "id": "/subscriptions/KC-EMEA-RSGP-NAVISIONKM-DEV-01/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/",
    "name": "km-emea-sqsrv-navision-tst-01/km-emea-sqdb-navision-tst-01"
  },
  {
    "Group": "KC-EMEA-RSGP-NAVISIONKM-DEV-01",
    "id": "/subscriptions/KC-EMEA-RSGP-NAVISIONKM-DEV-01/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/",
    "name": "km-emea-sqsrv-navision-tst-01/master"
  },
  {
    "Group": "KC-EMEA-RSGP-PROJECTS-DEV-01",
    "id": "/subscriptions/KC-EMEA-RSGP-PROJECTS-DEV-01/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/",
    "name": "kc-emea-sqsrv-projects-dev-01/KC-EMEA-SQDB-BPTRAINING-TRAINEE-01"
  }
]



$file = "pathtojsonfile.json"
$jsonContent = Get-Content $file | ConvertFrom-Json;

$namedb = $jsonContent.name;
$value= $namedb.Substring($namedb.IndexOf('/')+1) --> this doesn't work.
```

Comment: Shouldn't namedb.substring have a '$' in front of it?  And $namedb is an array.

Comment: Added $ before namedb, I forgot to copy in the question not in the script

Comment: .Indexof() works differently on arrays.  Try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try
`$namedb[0].Substring($namedb[0].IndexOf('/')+1)`
And for all of them:
`foreach($name in $namedb) {$name.Substring($name.IndexOf('/')+1)}`